# Inserting the \markangle on tkz-euclide 1.16c

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-collection

How do i insert `\markangle` in tkz-euclid 1.16c?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
  \tkzInit
  \tkzDefPoint(2,2){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}
  \tkzDefPoint(5,0){C}
  %angulos
  \tkzMarkAngle[fill=green!50,size=7mm](A,C,B)
  \tkzLabelPoints[right](C)
  \tkzDrawSegments(B,C C,A)
  \draw ($(C)+(165:.5)$) -- ($(C)+(165:.9)$);
  \draw[red,<-] ($(C)+(165:.9)$) to[out=180,in=0] +(-1,.5) node[left] {mark};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking.  You have an image that is produced by the quoted code. What do you want to do differently?

Answer (score 2):

Are you just trying to label the angle? If so just use `label={}` to specify what you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
  \tkzInit
  \tkzDefPoint(2,2){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}
  \tkzDefPoint(5,0){C}
  %angulos
  \tkzMarkAngle[fill=green!50,size=7mm,label={$35^\circ$}](A,C,B)
  \tkzLabelPoints[right](C)
  \tkzDrawSegments(B,C C,A)
  \draw ($(C)+(165:.5)$) -- ($(C)+(165:.9)$);
  %\draw[red,<-] ($(C)+(165:.9)$) to[out=180,in=0] +(-1,.5) node[left] {mark};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See my \markangle was done manually using the commands I wanted native tkz-euclide before existed, but now I found the command, nor in the manual. I need `\tkzMarkAngle[mark=x]` or similar.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva: Still not sure what you wanted, but if you have solved your issue you should post that as an answer here with some explanation.

Comment: I thought, is very simple: `\tkzMarkAngle[mark=|]`.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva: Simple or not, you should post the answer with an explanation. If you had a problem am sure others will too, and since my answer was not what you were looking for, so adding an answer might help others.